# Google Cast iOS API on iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, chromecast

I have a GoogleCast application working on my iPhone 4s. When I run the same application on the iPhone 4, it does not discover any Chromecast devices. Both phones are running 6.1.3. Does anyone know a reason why it won't work on the iPhone 4?

Answer (score 0):

Check again if iPhone 4 is on same WiFi network (I guess home network).
Usually you can check if you connect to router using browser (`http://192.168.1.1` or whichever is your router IP address - typically like your device IP address but with 1 at the end - last number). I suggest you try first using working device.

Also try to re-install Chromecast application.
Plus check if all applications you want to use (like YouTube) are updated.

Of course there can be many reasons, but you can start with these.